# Portlet Wizard for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, portlet

I'm starting to work with portlet(Websphere Portal) and all "how-to" in the web shows a Wizard(New Project -> Portlet Project) starter project for it, but i wouldn't able to find anyone that works in Eclipse Juno.
also, in IBM's RAD i could't find :/.
I tried to install http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/portlet-tools#.UMYj9nd8D0M but nothing happens. Is there a Wizard for Eclipse Juno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Juno, but if you want to create Portlet in Eclipse some plugins is unnecessary. You just need to create Dynamic Web Project and add Portlet jar as dependency\library\jar. http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286 Then you need to create java class that extends GenericPortlet, add portlet.xml descriptior and build your app (project - export - war) . Basic example http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v510/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/wpsbscfg.html